# How to stall program while waiting for image to load

Tags: ios, objective-c, sleep

How would you stall the program from executing? Doesn't sleep function do that? If it does, what's wrong with this code:

```
AsyncImageView *tmpImage = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:index];

int waitCounter = 0;
while (waitCounter < 10 && !tmpImage.imageIsLoaded) {
    waitCounter++;
    sleep(0.5);
}
NSLog(@"%i",waitCounter);
if (tmpImage.imageIsLoaded) {
    return [tmpImage image];
} else {
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"img_noimg.png"];
}
```

The AsyncImageView class loads an image from an URL then sets imageIsLoaded property to true. This usually happens quite fast (under a second), but if I scroll though the images like a madman, then it doesn't have time to load (it loads 10 images ahead).

I've added the while to prevent that from happening, but the log displays multiple cases of waitCounter being 10 while there was no sleep time (the interface didn't freeze).

Comment: Instead of (just) setting a property ´imageIsLoaded´ the method that receives the data could call a delegate method of the class to which the code sniplet belongs. That would then set the image accordingly. Abusing the sleep function is not a good idea.

Comment: Use class named "Async" and call sleep while Async request is complete... wow! Not best, not even good idea!
You shell read more about ios delegate, or about notification center. (i prefer delegate)

Comment: Um... I'd rather not want to dig into the code more then it's needed. I've already felt like jumping out the window 10 times while debugging other parts of this code (I'm managing a project, of which code was written in 2010)...

Comment: @LordZsolt If you ask questions on SO you might occasionally get alienated about your style of programming. Take it positive, and follow the advices.

Comment: As the others mentioned delegates and notifications in iOS allow your object to be informed when something occurs (such as an image finishes downloading. Forcing the sleep is REALLY inelegant, If you're interested I can help you implement a delegate or even easier a notification?

Comment: That's really kind of you, thank you. I'll be leaving for lunch, but if you want to help in about 1 or 2 hours, we can talk about it. I'll have to look into the AsyncImageView class a little.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try This, I guess it will work. Instead of

```
sleep(0.5);
```

try

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:.5f];
```

Comment: That's what I wanted, just not the way I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

One approach to solve a problem like this is to use a *completion handler*. A completion handler signals the call-site when an asynchronous task is complete and passes the result of the task as a parameter to the completion handler.

Your `AsyncImageView` class does have indeed such a completion handler. It's a selector. Today, one would use a block instead. The principle is the same, though.

Continuing after an async task has finished is called "Continuation". With blocks, you code looks as follows:

```
typedef void (^completion_handler_block)(id result);

void doSomethingAsync(completion_handler_block)completionHandler;

- (void) foo {

    doSomethingAsync(^(id result) {
        // Continuation code
        ...
    });

}
```

With blocks implementing continuation is especially easy, since it keeps the context (referenced variables defined in the call-site) within the block (closure).

Answer (score 0):

Where are you doing this? in method *cellForRowAtIndexPath* ?

If so, you must not sleep here.

For loading an image asynchronously you must

1) pass the real UIImageView to your AsyncImageView and

2) when you load the UIImage from URL, instead of set *_imageIsLoaded = TRUE*, you can load it directly in the passed UIImageView using *_imageView.image = image*

For instance you can do something like this, taking into account that maybe you already have the image loaded, etc. Create this method in AsyncImageView like this

```
-(void) reloadWithImageView:(UIImageView*)imageView {
    _imageView = imageView;
}
```

and when you later load the UIImage (probably in the *connectionDidFinishLoading* method)

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)aConnection {
    connection = nil;

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    _imageView.image = image;
}
```